# What is the difference between the roles Director of DevOps vs Head of DevOps and related areas of responsibility?

Tags: culture

Is there really a difference? Would "Director" lead several "Head of"?

Comment: I think this probably varies between institution, as with many job titles. Could you specify a specific situation (i.e. different job openings where you've seen this)? If not, I don't think there's enough information to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: Director is typically a US term, Head of something is more typical in EU corporations. It is just words, titles are fungible. But the whole concept of Director of DevOps is a little bit like Director of Teamwork. "Let's make this department of teamwork, name its director and all our teamwork will be done by those people. See how efficiently we solved a lack of teamwork?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear whether there is a clear difference between a Director of DevOps and a Head of DevOps, e.g. according to [this vacancy](https://www.comeet.co/jobs/naturalint/71.001/director-of-devops-and-it/56.405) both roles are the same, while according to [this](https://pete.wtf/2013/05/03/devops-in-your-job-title-is-doing-you-harm/) the Head of Devops is the owner and responsible for DevOps, while a [Director of DevOps](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7718989) is responsible for implementing a DevOps culture.